# combine while and if else in python 3

Tags: python

I am new in python and I was trying to make a little game "guess number" in python, If the input number is wrong, it will tell you its wrong and too big or too small, until you get the right one. but for now it wont show too big or too small just keep showing the wrong number
 here is my code (btw if I want to set up a specific retry time, how should I do it ? for example only can retry 3 times.)

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1,10)
guess = int(input("guess a number :"))
while guess != secret:
    guess = int(input("wrong, try again:"))

    if guess == secret:
        print("6666")
        print("88")
    else:
        if guess > secret:
            print("too large")
        else:
            print("too small")
```

Comment: python could be very flexible, but indentation matters, a lot

Comment: The code you show gives `IndentationError`, please show the code you are actually running.

Comment: Put your logic inside `while True` and use `break` to leave the loop

Comment: Hey i believe you should re-visit looping and if condition chapter in python. No offence but your basics are too weak

Comment: Thanks guys !!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, fix the indentation! In python it's important.
Here is sample code with retry (not optimal, it can be made better for sure):

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1,10)
guess = -1
num_retries = 3
while guess != secret and num_retries > 0:
    guess = int(input(f"Guess the number [retry {num_retries} out of 3]:"))

    if guess == secret:
        print("6666")
        print("88")
    else:
        if guess > secret:
            print("wrong, too large")
        else:
            print("wrong, too small")

    num_retries -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks !! but why you put guess = -1 here?

Comment: `guess = -1` is setting initial value so that is different from `secret` (which is in interval 1 to 10). First comparison `guess != secret` will be `False` in that case. Better would be set `guess = None`.